# effective dropdown login box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

First of all I found this [Simple and effective dropdown login box](http://red-team-design.com/simple-and-effective-dropdown-login-box/)

I upgrate sing up box.

Now I have Login and Sing up dropdown box, but I have problem

When I click on Login (activate) and after this I click on Sing up (activate second box), the login box don't up (not deactivated), now 2 box's is opened (activated)

I need if activated one of them, the second deactivated.

Here is the jQuery code (copy past)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                  

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
      $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
    else 
      $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
  });

  $('#registr-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#registr-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                  

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
      $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
    else 
      $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
  });
});
```

Thanks and sorry for my english

Here is example how it work now http://jsfiddle.net/ZcVCK/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/ZcVCK/3/)**

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
        $('#registr-content').slideUp();
        if ($('#registr-content').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#registr-content').find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        } else {
            $('#registr-content').find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
        }
        $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        } else {
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
        }
    });
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#registr-trigger').click(function () {

        if ($('#login-content').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#login-content').find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        } else {
            $('#login-content').find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
        }
        $('#login-content').slideUp();

        $(this).next('#registr-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        } else {
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether other box is open.

```
$('#login-trigger').click(function(){
$(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass('active'); 
if($('#registr-trigger').hasClass('active')){
  $('#registr-trigger').slideToggle();
  $('#registr-trigger').toggleClass('active'); 
}});
```

Similar code for `#registr-trigger`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
    $('#registr-trigger:visible').hide(); // <<<- new code
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                  

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    });
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#registr-trigger').click(function(){
    $('#login-trigger:visible').hide(); // <<<- new code
    $(this).next('#registr-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                  

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    });
});
```